# ASP.NET Core C# hosted on Linux cannot connect to the API

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core-mvc, httpclient

I am developing a website using asp.net core 7 and C#. This website retrieves data from the API using HttpClient and runs well on Windows OS. But when I hosted on Linux OS using Apache, I experienced problems that I could not connect directly to the API (Vendor), the data I got from the API did not match the data I expected. My analysis is that the problem is in SSL/TLS version 1.2 or TLS 1.3. Because when I try to make a CURL and wget connection on Linux what is displayed is SSL from the API.

Here is my HttpClient connection Initialization code:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IServerRequiredDataService, ServerRequiredDataService>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient((sp, httpClient) =>
    {            
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://subdomain.domain.com/");
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        UseCookies = true,
        AllowAutoRedirect = true,
        MaxConnectionsPerServer = 20,
        CheckCertificateRevocationList = true,
        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic,
        SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls13,
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; },
        CookieContainer = clientCookie
    });
```

Following are the test results using CURL:

```
* Connected to subdomain.domain.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=sni.cloudflaressl.com
*  start date: Jan 20 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 20 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "subdomain.domain.com" matched cert's "*.domain.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/2
* h2h3 [:method: GET]
* h2h3 [:path: /api/auth/data]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: subdomain.domain.com]
* h2h3 [accept: application/json, text/plain, */*]
* h2h3 [accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id;q=0.8]
* h2h3 [access-control-request-headers: x-app,x-domain-id,x-ismobile,x-language]
* h2h3 [access-control-request-method: GET]
* h2h3 [cache-control: no-cache]
* h2h3 [origin: https://target.com]
* h2h3 [referrer: https://target.com/]
* h2h3 [sec-fetch-dest: empty]
* h2h3 [sec-fetch-mode: cors]
* h2h3 [sec-fetch-site: cross-site]
* h2h3 [te: trailers]
* h2h3 [user-agent: MyBrowser]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x558b308cd8a0)
> GET /api/auth/data HTTP/2
> Host: subdomain.domain.com
> accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
> accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id;q=0.8
> access-control-request-headers: x-app,x-domain-id,x-ismobile,x-language
> access-control-request-method: GET
> cache-control: no-cache
> connection: keep-alive
> origin: https://target.com
> referrer: https://target.com/
> sec-fetch-dest: empty
> sec-fetch-mode: cors
> sec-fetch-site: cross-site
> te: trailers
> user-agent: MyBrowser
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
< HTTP/2 451
< date: Sun, 29 Oct 2023 02:17:23 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< cf-ray: XXXXXXXX-SIN
< cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< cache-control: no-cache, private
< access-control-allow-headers: *
< access-control-allow-methods: *
< x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.19
< x-ratelimit-limit: 10000
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 9999
< set-cookie: __cf_bm=f29fDiKLM5vDiQHoDr97S4awy8gGTEtyJhEWZjKBkyA-1698545843-0-AQyy/plbgl5zKcLuqzGId7rn+hBpdXPdh/ZW27Gplsr71yg+bNdwhQ9bRehqwWB3DiwWvDd583kpqx4MN34f/T8=; path=/; expires=Sun, 29-Oct-23 02:47:23 GMT; domain=.domain.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
< server: cloudflare
<
* Connection #0 to host subdomain.domain.com left intact
{"status":false,"ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","countryDetails":{"ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","iso_code":"XX","country":"xxxxxxx","city":"xxxxxxx","state":null,"state_name":null,"postal_code":"xxxxx","lat":1.3078,"lon":103.6818,"timezone":"Asia\/xxxx","continent":"AS","currency":"XXX","default":false},"livechat":{"livechat":"","livechat_type":""}}
```

and below I tried using openssl to retrieve SSL:

```
CONNECTED(00000003) depth=2 C = IE, O = Baltimore, OU = CyberTrust, CN
= Baltimore CyberTrust Root verify return:1 depth=1 C = US, O = "Cloudflare, Inc.", CN = Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3 verify return:1 depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "Cloudflare, Inc.", CN = sni.cloudflaressl.com verify return:1
--- Certificate chain  0 s:C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "Cloudflare, Inc.", CN = sni.cloudflaressl.com    i:C = US, O = "Cloudflare, Inc.", CN = Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3    a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 256 (bit); sigalg: ecdsa-with-SHA256    v:NotBefore: Jan 20 00:00:00 2023 GMT; NotAfter: Jan 20 23:59:59 2024 GMT  1 s:C = US, O = "Cloudflare, Inc.", CN = Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3    i:C = IE, O = Baltimore, OU = CyberTrust, CN = Baltimore CyberTrust Root    a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 256 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256    v:NotBefore: Jan 27 12:48:08 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Dec 31 23:59:59 2024 GMT
--- Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIFNTCCBNygAwIBAgIQC89DqAj4AFoBVfd1A+J4PzAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjBKMQsw CQYDVQQGEwJVUzEZMBcGA1UEChMQQ2xvdWRmbGFyZSwgSW5jLjEgMB4GA1UEAxMX Q2xvdWRmbGFyZSBJbmMgRUNDIENBLTMwHhcNMjMwMTIwMDAwMDAwWhcNMjQwMTIw MjM1OTU5WjB1MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQG A1UEBxMNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzEZMBcGA1UEChMQQ2xvdWRmbGFyZSwgSW5jLjEe MBwGA1UEAxMVc25pLmNsb3VkZmxhcmVzc2wuY29tMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZI zj0DAQcDQgAEe8MYPS13oWBoiu237V3Qqze7SEKyHHe+PNmA0IaM/If4bIrakqjz VMjShs9mFo9cyhOvWOscAl+loMFMVy5YVqOCA3cwggNzMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFKXO N+rrsHUOlGeItEX62SQQh5YfMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSGfGI6lo8BYjCUY0Lb1guZnGux NDBABgNVHREEOTA3ghVzbmkuY2xvdWRmbGFyZXNzbC5jb22CDWFwaS1vcGxiby5j b22CDyouYXBpLW9wbGJvLmNvbTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYI KwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMCMHsGA1UdHwR0MHIwN6A1oDOGMWh0dHA6Ly9jcmwz LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9DbG91ZGZsYXJlSW5jRUNDQ0EtMy5jcmwwN6A1oDOGMWh0 dHA6Ly9jcmw0LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9DbG91ZGZsYXJlSW5jRUNDQ0EtMy5jcmww PgYDVR0gBDcwNTAzBgZngQwBAgIwKTAnBggrBgEFBQcCARYbaHR0cDovL3d3dy5k aWdpY2VydC5jb20vQ1BTMHYGCCsGAQUFBwEBBGowaDAkBggrBgEFBQcwAYYYaHR0 cDovL29jc3AuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMEAGCCsGAQUFBzAChjRodHRwOi8vY2FjZXJ0 cy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vQ2xvdWRmbGFyZUluY0VDQ0NBLTMuY3J0MAwGA1UdEwEB /wQCMAAwggF7BgorBgEEAdZ5AgQCBIIBawSCAWcBZQB1AO7N0GTV2xrOxVy3nbTN E6Iyh0Z8vOzew1FIWUZxH7WbAAABhcz2ggsAAAQDAEYwRAIgJ4hdDcwtsEV5RsVN EefCbh12t/B2QcbQk8uSzjBVFG8CIH8cXKZcnAfjxuIo5gjOidab1IepIoQrGvn7 NxwwbXU1AHUASLDja9qmRzQP5WoC+p0w6xxSActW3SyB2bu/qznYhHMAAAGFzPaC LgAABAMARjBEAiBJhIe0f1LKlhm1TpG6ERvN59MOWX2sS949lfhtEem0rwIgKMTN f4MTjQfTcCPOF/sxt4nCQhtGwMcUDSofvd8gDDwAdQB2/4g/Crb7lVHCYcz1h7o0 tKTNuyncaEIKn+ZnTFo6dAAAAYXM9oJbAAAEAwBGMEQCIBs+3lAAEQHAPrT2FW2n
+ZjEqJa6nE0OitV3MUxP2a+LAiBAI9a9p5XVJUPMjx4gjr5Mj9uNubD1wD9wP0gW 7DlK2zAKBggqhkjOPQQDAgNHADBEAiAh8vmNeK/CFLQRIfgAnJKrpEDuXQ0x4NbD juNEc0v6hAIgc/sx4hSd7YfywXbk7YtWuiTKUlkjrMgV0lT6fyLLITI=
-----END CERTIFICATE----- subject=C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "Cloudflare, Inc.", CN = sni.cloudflaressl.com issuer=C
= US, O = "Cloudflare, Inc.", CN = Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3
--- No client certificate CA names sent Peer signing digest: SHA256 Peer signature type: ECDSA Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
--- SSL handshake has read 2628 bytes and written 334 bytes Verification: OK
--- New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 Server public key is 256 bit Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported Compression: NONE Expansion: NONE No ALPN negotiated Early data was not sent Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
--- Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived: SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 28BA50C279ACC3181906D3773DCC5BBF1E209ACB34A5C4A1D794F4D10DC632D1
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: E239501C4F340DCF06F6DD37FF821B73D5349DE285DA7A1C94D159B5E6D5C96660101200BCAE5531000843CA9173CE7C
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 64800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - e1 d9 1f 37 37 81 81 2f-19 4c a7 54 d5 41 40 1d   ...77../.L.T.A@.
    0010 - 34 41 02 51 a3 95 29 62-b7 e4 d3 80 98 31 3f 2e   4A.Q..)b.....1?.
    0020 - 9d 78 e9 30 14 0f 1f 68-4c bb 5e f2 32 66 a5 2e   .x.0...hL.^.2f..
    0030 - 92 7b 61 51 cc 18 87 83-25 b4 b5 cf d8 17 8a f3   .{aQ....%.......
    0040 - 4e d0 6c 2a 07 86 b9 bd-1b 9d 34 21 48 82 19 d6   N.l*......4!H...
    0050 - 23 a4 3c 64 a2 4c ea b4-35 1e 8e b7 43 33 75 76   #.<d.L..5...C3uv
    0060 - aa f2 74 c7 98 fd 84 7f-85 38 ea 59 b8 3c 90 85   ..t......8.Y.<..
    0070 - d3 80 6a 79 50 51 6a 7c-e1 38 5e 71 54 af 5f 29   ..jyPQj|.8^qT._)
    0080 - bf 38 b0 42 a8 2a 9e b2-84 e1 aa 51 8d b6 c4 eb   .8.B.*.....Q....
    0090 - 27 04 ae 0b 55 14 42 08-fc fc 62 5d e7 fe e5 1b   '...U.B...b]....
    00a0 - cf 42 07 92 12 f5 82 ef-bc cd 41 a3 e8 7d 13 39   .B........A..}.9
    00b0 - 86 c5 e0 cc b6 4b 2f 48-9a 53 e6 eb b9 25 cc 5c   .....K/H.S...%.\

    Start Time: 1698552034
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
--- read R BLOCK
--- Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived: SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 2B354BA3A7A4768CF2A909AF7619773D28597220A7756A8E3FFBACD8AAECE55B
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: D80BA5F9189BB16ADBC317D364D75832D34ED48D6EDD5E2D1C0498FD472F8BAB0E9C415CCE97F27CDA634BBDFE6065E1
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 64800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - e1 d9 1f 37 37 81 81 2f-19 4c a7 54 d5 41 40 1d   ...77../.L.T.A@.
    0010 - 06 cc c3 e8 1f 38 00 6c-96 0f 27 db ee 99 27 34   .....8.l..'...'4
    0020 - a5 fb 34 0a 6d 9d 56 79-ed 82 bf 6d 8a dd a9 ea   ..4.m.Vy...m....
    0030 - 0e 6d 77 ab 87 c6 ad 64-67 9e 96 e9 27 eb fe fc   .mw....dg...'...
    0040 - 7d 02 78 42 06 25 90 93-5a 52 a4 1f 12 5f 3c f3   }.xB.%..ZR..._<.
    0050 - 4d 77 e6 d9 30 1e d4 51-50 13 bb 28 62 eb 19 06   Mw..0..QP..(b...
    0060 - e7 f9 fe b5 2b 50 2d 7b-15 70 66 8d 95 d2 20 0c   ....+P-{.pf... .
    0070 - 14 f0 65 e4 30 95 56 7d-91 40 fb 28 56 ea f4 1d   ..e.0.V}.@.(V...
    0080 - f2 6d 17 e3 be 53 f9 38-f8 25 82 06 66 d2 2c e4   .m...S.8.%..f.,.
    0090 - 10 b3 af 58 7c ff bf 7c-2a 54 d0 d8 50 85 f1 d5   ...X|..|*T..P...
    00a0 - 0b 3c 11 19 b3 7f 78 6b-15 e9 2b 63 bc 34 38 dc   .<....xk..+c.48.
    00b0 - 48 2e 0c 8e 76 a8 d4 b2-79 67 69 ec 4d 13 54 2e   H...v...ygi.M.T.

    Start Time: 1698552034
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
--- read R BLOCK closed
```

Have you experienced the same thing or maybe you have a solution to this problems?

Comment: use this code:`new HttpClientHandler
        {
            SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13,
        };`
ServicePointManager` is not supported in .NET Core and later versions, including ASP.NET Core. You should remove these lines from your code:`ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;`. Temporarily try to disable Certificate Validation

Comment: when you get data, the problem is beyond the `SSL/TLS` because, the `SSL/TLS` step happens before you be able to send or receive data. you should find the problem in the application layer.